# error in R.java with a boolean instead of assignment

Tags: android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view that extends the LinearLayout, has a TextView as a component and inflates a layout I created. Everything is fine, but I get this error

"public static final int LInearLayout_width==0x7f07000a"

It's the "==" instead of an "=" and I can't modify the R.java file. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

R.java error is really mind freaking. Just delete your R.java file and build your project. If it doesn't solve then restart your eclipse.